# Flask-MongoEngine AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_or_404'

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I followed Flask-MongoEngine tutorial and use the code below:

```
tag = Tag.objects.get_or_404(slug=tag_slug)
```

it raised an AttriubteError:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_or_404'
```

my pip freeze:

```
mongoengine==0.11.0
pymongo==3.4.0
Flask==0.12
flask-mongoengine==0.8.2
Flask-WTF==0.14
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove ‍`mongoengine` from your pip freeze and in model definition import `Document` from `flask_mongoengine`, not from `mongoengine`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that `tag = Tag.objects().get_or_404(slug=tag_slug)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add BaseQuerySet as the "queryset_class"

WRONG:

```
import mongoengine
from mongoengine import Document

db = mongoengine

class Tag(db.Document):
    field = db.StringField()

    meta = { 'collection': 'tags' }
```

RIGHT:

```
import mongoengine
from flask_mongoengine import BaseQuerySet
from mongoengine import Document

db = mongoengine

class Tag(db.Document):
    field = db.StringField()

    meta = { 'collection': 'tags', 'queryset_class': BaseQuerySet}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach the Tag class to the model scheme?

Maybe you have an error in model file.

You could create a model file that includes a Tag class to test if the `get_or_404` method works now.

`model.py`

```
from mongoengine import *

class Tag(Document):
  slug = StringField()
  name = StringField()

  ....
  other attributes
```

And maybe now you can do it that:

```
def slug(tag_slug):
  tag = Tag.objects.get_or_404(slug=tag_slug)
```

Try it and you tell us.

Comment: I'm sorry if my English is bad... I was just trying to help. :(

Comment: If this is in fact an answer, please expand by posting the details of what you're proposing that might solve the original poster's problem